# External display momentarily turns on while macbook pro is in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

I've done a lot of searching around but can't find a question/answer online quite matching the situation I'm experiencing. There are really a ton of similar questions that are somewhat different as well (every problem possible with an external monitor is out there such that many are quite similar, yet not exactly the same), so this class of problem really seems to lie in the subtle details. Here goes:

Problem:

- I have an external display connected via a usb-c cable. After I lock
  my macbook pro, the screen will turn off in 15 minutes.
- At this point, the external display can **turn on** every few minutes or every few hours. **It turns on momentarily and just goes
  back into power saving mode again immediately.**
- After I wake up in the morning, I think this happens enough such that the monitor won't turn on unless I unplug it from the power and
  plug it in again.

Now's the weird parts:

- I've done all the typical suggestions. Replacing cables, changing
  ports. I have reset nvram, I turned off wake-for-wifi, disabled power nap, etc... At that point, I thus concluded it must be a problem due with my P2415Q Dell monitor.
- However, I recently tried a new monitor, an HP Z27 monitor, and it has the same exact problem.
- Ok, so it's possible it's the mac, or it's possible that both monitors are problematic.
- I ruled out the latter by connecting BOTH monitors and having only one on at the time, and the problem happens only for the monitor that is turned on, but only to ONE monitor when BOTH are turned on.

Here's why I haven't contacted Apple yet.

- Honestly, I rather share the knowledge if we can find an answer here.
  I also have little hope in them due to the complexity/details that I
  mentioned in the start of my post.
- But mostly, this problem occurred with the previous generation Macbook pro I used in 2017 running El Capitan. I'm now running Mojave
  on a 2019 Macbook pro. I feel like this must be a common problem, and
  I am hoping that someone out there has found a solution or can at
  least sympathize with me and give me a virtual pat on the shoulder.

Thank you

Comment: I'm still not sure what happened, but I think it's possible it's due to an imperfect usb-c cable. I recommend the expensive name brand ones that can deliver 80+ watts.